# Why isn't the copy-constructor called when passing rvalue by value to function

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor, pass-by-value, c++98

It's a thing which I missed somehow, but I am surprised. Consider the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int a;

public:
    A(int a) : a(a) { std::cout << "Normal constructor called." << std::endl; }
    A(const A& orig) : a(orig.a) { std::cout << "Copy constructor called." << std::endl; }
};

void testFunction1(const A arg) { std::cout << "testFunction1()" << std::endl; }
void testFunction2(const A& arg) { std::cout << "testFunction2()" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
   testFunction1(A(2));

   testFunction2(A(2));

   return 0;
}
```

I expected the following result:

```
/* Normal constructor called. */
/* Copy constructor called. */
/* testFunction1() */
/* Normal constructor called. */
/* testFunction2() */
```

But I was wrong. The exact result was the following:

```
/* Normal constructor called. */
/* testFunction1() */
/* Normal constructor called. */
/* testFunction2() */
```

Why wasn't the copy constructor called when I passed `A(2)` by value to `testFunction1()`? Does it mean that there is no difference between passing an rvalue by value or reference in C++98? Is it an optimization? Is `A(2)` and `arg` *totally the same* object in `testFunction1()`?

Comment: Probably [*copy elision*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Thanks, I will check it. Never heard about that before.

Comment: If you never heard about that, then you might read some good C++ books... **Meyers** and **Sutter** books are highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it an optimization?

Yes! It's called *[Copy Elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)*, where a copy can be elided (bypassed), if possible, depending on the compiler.

So in your case, the compiler understands that it can get away without calling the copy constructor, and does exactly this. Note that even if you used `arg`, like for example calling a printing member function of `A`, copy elision could still be employed by the compiler, for optimization purposes. In other words, not using `arg` is not the cause of this behavior.

If you use an ancient compiler, or temper the settings of your current one, you will probably see the result you expected at the first place.

With [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), copy elision would be guaranteed in this case, as Guillaume Racicot mentioned.

Comment: I'd even mention that it's guaranteed to have copy elision in his case in C++17